# display audio stream title in iOS notification center

Tags: iphone, audio, stream, notifications, element

I have a WebView-app in which HTML5 audio elements play streams.

When, on my iPhone, I play a stream and bring up the notification center (by sliding up from the bottom of the screen), I do see the audio controls, but not the title of the stream.

How do I add a title to the streams so that at least some info about the stream is displayed below the audio controls in the notification center?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, you can set it using the .title property of the Audio object.